# Найти экранирование в C#

Tags: c#, строки, экранирование

Изучаю C# и столкнулся с проблемой.

Есть задача извлечь из строки подстроку от кавычки до конца строки или кавычки(неизвестно какой именно, ' или ").

При этом, нужно игнорировать экранированные кавычки \' и \", но учитывать их в длину получившейся подстроки.

Например в метод подается строка "a \"c\"" а выходит a "c" длина 7 символов.

Как я только не сравниваю символы подающей строки, не через равенство не через compare я не могу найти, чем отличается в моей строке ' от \' и, следовательно, длину строки тоже не могу понять правильно.

```
public static Token ReadQuotedField(string line, int startIndex)
    {
        int start = startIndex;
        int end = startIndex;
        char Separator = line[startIndex]; //гарантируется что строка начинается с какой то кавычки.
        end++;
        while (end != line.Length && (line[end] != Separator))
        {
            end++;
        }
        return new Token(line.Substring(start+1, end-start-1), startIndex, Math.Min(end-start+1, line.Length));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что условия данной задачи подразумевают, что на вход строка подается в строгом соответствии, с @.
То есть не "'a\' b'"
a @"'a\' b'"
и когда мы начинаем работать со строкой, достаточно найти символ '\\' и убрать его из результирующей строки, то есть не нужно сравнивать ' и \'
спасибо за внимание, надеюсь кому то пригодится

```
public static Token ReadQuotedField(string line, int startIndex)
    {
        int start = startIndex;
        int end = startIndex;
        char Separator = line[startIndex];
        var result = "";
        end++;
        while ((end != line.Length) && (line[end] != Separator ^ line[end-1] == '\\'))
        {
            var symbol = line[end];
            if (symbol != '\\')
                result += symbol;
            end++;
        }
        return new Token(result, startIndex, Math.Min(end-start+1, line.Length));
    }
```